# OutOfMemory exception when loading an image in .Net

Tags: c#, .net

Im loading an image from a SQL CE db and then trying to load that into a PictureBox.

I am saving the image like this:

```
if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                picArtwork.ImageLocation = ofd.FileName;
                using (System.IO.FileStream fs = new System.IO.FileStream(ofd.FileName, System.IO.FileMode.Open))
                {
                    byte[] imageAsBytes = new byte[fs.Length];
                    fs.Read(imageAsBytes, 0, imageAsBytes.Length);
                    thisItem.Artwork = imageAsBytes;
                    fs.Close();
                }
            }
```

and then saving to the Db using LINQ To SQL.

I load the image back like so:

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"C:\Temp\img.jpg", FileMode.CreateNew ,FileAccess.Write ))
                {
                    byte[] img = (byte[])encoding.GetBytes(ThisFilm.Artwork.ToString());
                    fs.Write(img, 0, img.Length);
                }
```

but am getting an OutOfMemoryException. I have read that this is a slight red herring and that there is probably something wrong with the filetype, but i cant figure what.

Any ideas?

Thanks
                    picArtwork.Image = System.Drawing.Bitmap.FromFile(@"C:\Temp\img.jpg");

Comment: What is the type of thisItem.Artwork?  You're assigning bytes to it in the first code block, but in the second code block you're converting Artwork ToString, and then converting that to bytes.  Why the multiple conversions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the code you provided it seems like you are treating the image as a string, it might be that data is being lost with the conversion from byte[] to string and string to byte[].

I am not familiar with SQL CE, but if you can you should consider treating the data as a byte[] and not encoding to and from string.

I base my assumption in this line of code

```
byte[] img = (byte[])encoding.GetBytes(ThisFilm.Artwork.ToString());
```

Comment: I removed the .ToString() and it worked like a charm. Well spotted. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

The GDI has the bad behavior of throwing an OOM exception whenever it is not capable of understanding a certain image format. Use Irfanview to see what kind of image that really is, it is likely GDI can't handle it.

Comment: Well it's a file that i have added myself, so i know its a .jpg. Does .Net do any transformation of the format?

Comment: It shouldn't mangle the format, but if it does, it certainly ought to be a format GDI supports, since it's coming from GDI.

Answer (score 0):

My advice would be to not use a FileStream to load images unless you need access to the raw bytes.  Instead, use the static methods provided in Bitmap or Image objects:

```
Image img = Image.FromFile(@"c:\temp\img.jpg")
Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.FromFile(@"c:\temp\img.jpg")
```

To save the file use .Save method of the Image or Bitmap object:

```
img.Save(@"c:\temp\img.jpg")
bmp.Save(@"c:\temp\img.jpg")
```

Of course we don't know what type `ArtWork` is.  Would you care to share that information with us?